# sdf_nrow, collect() and sdf_collect() on the same sparklyr data.frame returns different tables as outputs

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, dbplyr

I have a sparklyr data.frame `patsEnrollment`
I convert this to a native R data.frame using two different methods; one using `sdf_collect()` and the other by using `collect()` function within dplyr. I am quite baffled by the fact that the table outputs are different in both these outputs! Not only this, if I do sdf_nrow() on the sparklyr data.frame I get a different count too. Here's the R code:

```
patsEnrollment1 <- sdf_collect(patsEnrollment)
patsEnrollment2 <- patsEnrollment %>% collect()
print(nrow(patsEnrollment1))
print(nrow(patsEnrollment2))
print(sdf_nrow(patsEnrollment))
```

And this is the output I get in the console

```
> print(nrow(patsEnrollment1))
[1] 1077142
> print(nrow(patsEnrollment2))
[1] 1293446
> print(sdf_nrow(patsEnrollment))
[1] 1213967
```

Ideally, it should all return the same result, but all three are different.

UPDATE:

Here's the output of glimpse

```
> glimpse(patsEnrollment)
Rows: ??
Columns: 4
Database: spark_connection
$ enrolid <int64> 2805363, 20596958
$ dobyr   <int> 1997, 2004
$ dtstart <dttm> 2009-01-01, 2014-03-01
$ dtend   <dttm> 2009-01-31, 2014-03-31
```

Comment: Can you share some info about the table structure or variable types?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. added

Comment: I think I found the reason. There was an SQL query to construct my sparklyr data.frame which uses a 'limit' clause. I think everytime I try to execute the code multiple times, each time the limit query is also getting executed (because lazy evaluation) and this is a random process.